# SVG thumbnails black on live server

Tags: assets

On my MAMP development server, SVG files display like this in the Assets section of the Control Panel:

[image]

On my live server, they get a black background:
[image]

When I use an SVG file inside an `img` tag with an transform like this:

```
<img src="{{ iconSVG.getUrl(iconSize) }}">
```

I got this working fine on the MAMP server, but on the live server the file gets transformed into a PNG with a black background.

I don't necessarily have to use a transform on the SVGs, so could leave that out, but the black thumbs in the Assets isn't that pretty.

I checked both servers, and a possibly relevant difference I can see is that the MAMP does not have **imagick**, whereas the live server does.

How can I fix the black thumbnail issue? Would I need to disable **imagick** on the live server somehow?

Comment: I think [Craft will prefer GD](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/requirements) if it is installed, and only fall back on imagick, so I'd start checking if the live env has GD installed. I can also vaguely remember a similar issue with imagemagick and CMYK colors, but I can't remember any specifics.

Comment: @megatrond Close!  Craft will prefer Imagick and fall back to GD if it's not available.

Comment: Oh, I had it backwards then! I still can remember something about CMYK and black results from imagemagick though.

Answer (score 1):

Craft requires [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to do any SVG transforms, so that fact that it is working on your MAMP install without it is the only weird thing I see here. :)

Craft will attempt to use Imagick if it is available on the server and fallback to GD otherwise or you can explicitly tell it which one to use via the [imageDriver](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#imageDriver) config setting.

As to why it's all black on production, make sure you're using a recent version of both the Imagick [PHP extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) as well as the underlying [Imagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I've added the `'imageDriver' => 'gd'` setting to the config file and now get the default SVG file icon in the assets area, which isn't perfect but better than a black square :)

I've asked my host to upgrade ImageMagick, as the current version on the server I use is from 2012.